# Push to git on GIthub to re-trigger missed 'push' webhook

Tags: git, github, github-webhook

I've pushed some changes to repository on Github with `git push origin master`, but one of webhooks was not triggered because of network failures. This webhooks is configured to send only "push" events. Is it possible to push nothing via `git` CLI to retrigger webhooks for latest commit (which is already pushed)?

I can't do that via Github settings web-page, because I'm not the admin in this repo. I know that I can push some commit and revert it back, but I don't want to  pollute git history. Force push won't work because of `master` branch protection settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A message only commit might help you :

```
git commit --allow-empty
```